# Why we didn't apply mean value theorem for the definite integral in this way?

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

To find Taylor Remainder of $\log(1-t)$ we need to evaluate following integral with mean value theorem :

$$\int_0^t\frac{x^{n+1}}{1-x}dx=\frac1{1-c}\int_0^t x^{n+1}dx=(\frac{1}{1-c})\frac{t^{n+2}}{n+2}$$
for some $c$ between $0$ and $t$.

But My question is how we recognized we should take out $\frac{1}{1-x}$ from integral? why not taking out $x^{n+1}$ from integral and calculating $c^{n+1}\int_0^t \frac1{1-x}dx$?

Comment: Well, try it. You will get $\log$ back again and then......

Comment: @Matematleta Oh this is true. I am new to using mean value theorem for integrals.In general Can we take out any function we want ( with consideration for example being non-negative and contionus ...) from integral?

Comment: You need one of them to be integrable and positive.  If you do the proof you will see why this is so.

Comment: Is it possible both functuin have this condition? If yes then we choose which one?

Comment: $f_n(x)=x^n$ won't work because it is $0$ at $0$ right? If both are $+$ then you can use either one.

Comment: Oh I got it. Thank you

Comment: You are welcome. Glad to help.